# Telerik RadGrid set specific cell readonly based on CheckBox State

Tags: javascript, c#, checkbox, telerik, radgrid

I'm using a RadGrid to show several columns referring ID, Name, etc. One column contains a value to change, another one is a column containing a checkbox (in a GridTemplateColumn). Now I want to disable the value cell(!) based on the state of the checkbox (i.e. checkbox checked = cell disabled).

Two ways have to be considered: 
- First load of the Grid, all value cells have to be disabled in which the checkbox is already ticked
- on changing the checkbox, the cell has to be enabled/disabled.

Sadly, I wasn't able to achieve this behaviour at all, neither with javascript nor with C#.

Any help would be very appreciated!